# How lost phone finding Apps ring the iphone even in Silent mode and App Killed stated

Tags: iphone, silent, playsound

There are many 'Apple Device Finder' Apps in the store. Many of them help the user to ring the iphone even when the phone is in silent mode. I am trying to find out how this is achieved. How can we play sound on the iPhone which is the silent mode. Anyone knows the Apple-supported Framework or library to achieve this. I have not found any threads on how can an app makes phone ring on silent mode and even in the app killed state. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually doubt that's possible. I think just iCloud "Find my iPhone" feature is able to do that.

For example, TuneIn alarm feature requires app to be open. If you kill the app, effectively it can't do anything. The only thing it would be able to do is to receive a push notification; but that's not handled by the app itself, but the OS.

Comment: What about chipolo ios app. I found it rings even in the killed state and even in silent mode of the device.

Comment: I think I'm going to swallow my words. Please see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297132/swift-3-how-to-override-silent-mode-and-play-audio-from-background