# Need to play a sound when app is in background and silent mode is on

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to make a timer app with a very simple interface. The problem is that there's no way to run a code block in the background and local notifications can't play a sound when the phone is in silent mode. I have found apps like stretch which are catering to this particular use case.

I have tried solving this issue using local notifications but local notifications can't play sound when silent mode is turned on.

Comment: I think I found a similar question.
[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297132/swift-3-how-to-override-silent-mode-and-play-audio-from-background):

Comment: I've never used Stretch, but apps that I know, such as MultiTimer, are _not_ able to solve this problem, so I believe it cannot be solved. Maybe Stretch uses the cheating method of playing a silent sound continuously in the background to keep itself alive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` for playing sound when device is in silent mode; usage:

```
 do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
 }
 catch {
    // report for an error
 }
```

Comment: I won't be able to run this code when the app is in background. The only use case I'm having a problem with is when the app is in background and silent mode is on